# PHP Download Script displaying Mnemonics

Tags: php

So this script works fine with wamp server but when i uploaded my files to godaddy hosting. it displayed a file full of mnemonic like codes.

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('variables/variable.php');
$tbl_name="videos"; // Table name 
// Connect to server and select databse.
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con) or die("cannot select DB");
$result=$_REQUEST['id'];
$sql="SELECT sav_fname,ori_fname FROM $tbl_name WHERE vdo_code='$result'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$result=mysql_fetch_object($result);


$myfile ="upload/".$result->sav_fname;

if(file_exists($myfile))
{
// Add bellow code for mime type
$temp = explode(".",$myfile);
$ext = strtolower(end($temp));
$mime_types = array(

        // video
        '3gp' => 'video/3gpp',
        '3g2' => 'video/3g2',
        'avi' => 'video/avi',
        'mp4' => 'video/mp4',
        'asf' => 'video/asf',
        'mov' => 'video/quicktime',
    );
if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)){
   $mm_type=$mime_types[$ext];
}
else{
   $mm_type="application/octet-stream";
}

//header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Type: ".$mm_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$result->ori_fname);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($myfile));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($myfile);
}
else
{
echo "Unable to Download File, File Not Found";
}


?>
```

This is just a small part of what is displayed in when downloader.php is executed.

ftypmp42mp42isomavc1„free8x­mdatÞlibfaac 1.28B“ 2G! I#€!Gþÿ‹–ðšºû€øþ¹ÞÿŸû'Ô>¶¦æúGäŸx¿Ê@ù þÁáþ3ïÀÌçÕzúsñ÷èýŽÃÏ9ùÜ^–¯Æ÷²€‘øR†@àp!HþÿËÒc“‘)/OözwêØö^ˆ{ÚÛ/(¨[žÜ@uðÆ5A ò\ÙQ—÷h›Íž‹~œµËæÿž9§ŠÀhCx´š„ÅQ#ü‡ØÃ;•l*ï‹¬Q¬“†BÒˆ5Jcp×Ã³Õ Õ«ù/T`Z™‘À!IþÿåàÑ„Æ”&N%¾?ï]V'ç·äìn~.ÂÏ+¯>ÇnŸ®>¿ë³1$Üó@©sY<Á‚«è å)ü*ÍÃš'ˆ&q‰$=‡¯"¤T'ÝAæ¦²™€*Ín8qÊZÁ«kP>ÔjÃxÒŒn#þ7ùÕî»ÿ§ý?æÿ7ùßý_êÿwÜêþŸqÿêýOþà?õê2C€!IþÿåéAc    H“&¯YõþžÃ„Ü·)ò¬îï òMº£'ÃF¸ Å`ÂªÏ»Ü³•))R®GyÿÀÚšƒÐí—U˜7ê•0«uØ”‹ºY=¢"TU¹ÂMðÃV£ºØ.â‚cófÄ¦ ž9¢î÷#æ;@öÁ«V£ùùÏåü¦ûOý¿ûCÿÓíÿSÿêýHd‡!Iþÿå©Bd¥“SŒýÎÆO¡¬¸ìÕè Î?d„ÉÌ´9Þ7É4—yRr­;ÒÀdÿr\BjK1äBéã  ÑžÓX@û‰˜sXœåUŽtÑkã÷» n"Ýl/§6OŽ`¨=X  l­ÛbG!CÚ?¤Žÿæÿ3¿üoøßêÿS¿üŸþ¿åq³dGóþÏ~ûå¬¡À!HþÿÉÓ†åJIyçþ£à¹Þ³Ôýî‡PÝ5A“ÝU²ö‡²uXÀVþ2ª‘“ÁÉ›+ôŠY;mŸ±<ÕÁUáÌ½äÔªyÏçM(g…”à„'Ðé(…@9*Œ°)Uª(§ufª–Fði˜‡¶'”0xïÇÏ†4àè™‰ð˜™‚bc8ÌÝ‘ÀêÿÿæÜEé½æÙH·–,Ø Ù#îïx264 - core 130 r2273 b3065e6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=35.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=20000 vbv_bufsize=25000 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00€ ~eˆ„Ÿå{ÿ­,a](cÖÂ½  Øôy)’û/Æ#×–ÍÌ ;gÁš±}ïg±56¤#T6WÀ£ÿ”/r¹*ŒÊ¡ÍØI²k E6ÃÉ‚XÝýB“ó  ½–FŽœ   ·ÌY{ròì(DJÒ"X“y§&8]´&Éd«pòÃ+ "è¶_¬Pt‚> ¾.ƒ=õÆ.€‘UjZ»Ú†7MŽ¼ƒo× øœ]ë¾Ñƒ¨…U0Òïè²XLà¢‰~Æ+‘xâ9Æº<ˆŠÄzÂÃ)ìÌkâ‰jžäÖ}á&5žsÀ´µ‡x{Fâ&‡­Ÿ è'ÂJ™ÁªÞ0`}mE!êåÃØÓ^Ý    œœ•Èm}'Ëï@3'C+1¨hmE”ž=Þ£,Óã×ÑÌY¥g£áyµ¥**Æ}×xÜnûzèEk”êžØ'´­V€þÓŠ9ê”êƒ8±åÃn0Ww::'ýY4C¦S|rôC=$c°Çq:iœl¬#ZPgùw•Â:+CDãÐ™ÊCÄ•Ì²L7ì<7ï$YWˆÆpx  ¾ìnIó*.å«gólOoŠ’ä@•qõ\¦°‚8ÁU`dÅÉÌh  ¹Ìñnö`%Ÿ3°g¡ßŒ¿Uû‡¸[‚ê9ˆ?ùùÝ‰èüWwM€S8”Þ®Ýø[ÚÕëðòw„]ˆ^Ó—ï_{žb©·â–žöáQ¨VÚ¹ÏŒŽžªuÜ*‡ÿÖ%-ØÅdÊ£ôÉî¦]Å@¢6±5MÜ¤¶©áïÈ®ŒƒV=ãvèÖî#cä–YS  Ú–êáªªÄB†È-J rJØ5ëÖšýÑŠrÁû0~LtÜ‰­(¥wœ­Ÿ€ kxekÈâÇ¿Ù¹¨‘æŠÐ½Þó°zÁ‰òüÅ?óã~œ!ÿG½”ØÍ‹  ˜½@ é;'] Þ‹(®+9l§Yì"1øÅ"4…r^+$ˆ#¯,Vv”=âûöö—&RÉ\ò0}Å&B7Ñ)SáÐ‡‡-4`.L§Ñ–¼Ó;F 1hz…þb+\Nöžm×V¶gµßˆÄ%#¦{»„z¬å²\$¬ÒíAgÔyzè‹ÁvQ%pA˜`Ið8Kò“Ð#K)µ1ˆ–ä%ÒåLÞ!ˆOœ˜‹‰?2.M¯ˆ“-¦ãiÖ%˜>/-a4’*uó¡BÙ…ÿå&€ §IQj´üÔoa9“ h; Ây±µm¾¦ë&*Ê,ûJôOÁÛÐ_º<Â3÷¿   ›ô½["R­ñ‰$ÅŸ7—÷Ž~rsrŽµŽ¹äŽ=ÅŒiËBñmYS¼(q—ôvl*èùƒéP¸%Í²™ýQœë¡Qš‡iŒä¡‚cãG­¥Ý ²üŠ5°M‚‚*¨`4Úç¢à]»À´¶Ôä-Š\›ØÇÛ=\·Õwräñº¾ü¿•MôÒ×§m£ói&¹÷ÝØÑÈ;É“ßîw×J¼á{yEþ»4H‚’û(–Ýl¢Ê]¾w‹éGpDÿzÙ§”/ºÊ[­º‚¿)¢ö›¬HÎÕûXÚyŒEŒg¼[¯‰¬.§úÙØ¤·†[l÷z*WJ2Ë±…Oèf-àV´áœS[áï-‡[Xwz€uÑØAè:%gµ( Ù‰Å„.1¹$MMÿÙC8}]Z-'P“}S~½Œæ=!÷X´F¤+ù¨7 ¹¥_lÃ‚¥»aœÂ‡T*Õ¹ul$á®)ºgÉ§ÙžûT=ØÆX0÷êùèx·SÆŒ—m{‹ušsè^Pì•æ`6.¾Ð7¯÷r‰,Xøç{w\wÊuŽ%µœí8?êâúâàÿ_ògämYÆÓçÇÀñ‡÷SÞüÒ“,rW¤vn¯×Åð£‡ômT¾G´bIÚ   ˆÞ´Ršr[Òá,Mhu£{%HêHÂN{k†$¤ÍBÇìGç†ç1., ä0åO½ fœ «B"Ü;¼ ¤Î[BZ³NÌZÔã¸Ù‚yCÛÏÅ^#Þìë  ?Aõ9µ`` `|Üb¨ƒY‡Ú¡F˜õ>^#[´Ä‡Rìñ¬³¶}ßC ``EåJ–oÒ‚#‰¶äÐg>ê¤    äu•Ö)†¿#¤û^æ‚Èýf·˜õ¢¢U0ý“·d´ú˜½¾ã‘Ž3r‹nëÌylœâ'Þ›f×ë\–f¬ÅG¸ûNÑ(Vè‰âìCk…È8É*’ÉÛ…ùÅÐëMŽu¥Øº]i2ú,ðJŒÚ0£Û•#Ìç¿H-FüÑeÝ|þ›’ç²Ô³‰!†‹³áQ|‚.Š–fUÝ#€¦é,Ö!š+«%7!JÂ•{€h5Û|   hÇ’¨s°"lö`Ó9zÞ=7VðƒuäËo¾'Q…‘åÚÎ u(©ÑO©Ìý$hnÚyë‰™ŸNýužA%”éðp‘Àhy"¼À“ð¿ZÄI¦}™8¢œã27 5+LÆd2) ™#WBòËª   Ì9T°™z¦—Žö^ê 5f÷5Ôåó<êm6D+×gµµj·fúx;áñœÜ}½$:„õnqF©Ì`apÄC@ÚqýöŽÎ–›Ú hD   ‰®•9 ÅÑ.ßÆ™jaÀï @€ÑõPEÉ"£}ŸE ôCJlwý/Æ\¦†èñÈ=Uáâ7û<®“#Õ‡ž½›NÞN,x*¾¸r•GdÅ5zº]Ò€LÂ‚‘ÙV”±úä…P˜6´óÎô€°8³bÜGèÙ.•/¢*¼óò;~Ù}ÞF`ßgßçµ;5ãŠ8—«úÓàƒ1Ù—__sgá…çøÖš®”–=êE4%‡]2ãÅ {ÜcF®ž×1BÉW‘à#BI²V>z¶AµîÌ‹Ãºý¦"øã†/UŠz38é^-†¹æ#_ÀGöˆÌ "YqÊÅj|&ðÁ€ì?‡æ½âd´üíIÂÚqpóèœ¾²½;‚MÇú¸Büz‹·)g"7³e   ¼ÕQ|æ&PM‡çTÉ¡õ“wÏ|SdW…3Dj¸=Ê+±÷ñÖ?•…X®… ³NOPôtÔ°à lº¨ÖÂ‹ËCÈè'Œoj{ÂGŽZÏGÉ9\Ú°é³{Ž}¢–@Œ)M‹5¡'›íì(%Ë°4Ãßª@òµ˜DžMÐŒ”,¾ÈÑÑHÑÏôh`žÉ¬Ï®—Á;<>x¡sI;å¥U   ã5º57ßåØ/£ÚÁèéz˜?Âj×’c. ˜uaIÒUvËùÆËèwDI9üÏ£Œ°Z¹|ñ¸ú<…o¿f×†:£<©KØ¿.²ìXV¢U!DN6“AÛËúzåHäAà#Ÿ~G?ïóë•1“¤e&Vb?â$©¹p¬Ì±YJàKSy-–×ïsLhuJIè9ˆ“Çk%ð¥«bqN¼¥ç»êRÃ¤gœbiï*ßo:Á!ì¡ÿ$]®¹÷_ ë·a«Wä(by^ÉÕMöD$s ‚7¡wð/«)˜ª‡P®v˜¯an¿®:Z‘hÓ>¤³ù{‚âD!žý×ºº×D©B){qjO"ùt’+ó eðÑ‰:©Ê¿‘Å}¡ÆáiÿâÖ4:fë4yf$ÈÙ…¶FÃƒf$ãÉˆ"çh±‰õ.ºþÃ¹‡;-DG;fÈã‘¤I°{µæ´ÜÏ9htù€ðô  'ò„wnèu1/UÖÿìõ)]…1eˆnžœú§DF€P¶sT6õOùÙ\ùšÛ…Kœ= ¸À‚S¥¾¯µL |clÑ²U| h8WÑaÚ‚,‰W'pN[– © ÿç…ï·s<'‚o„   qUöÔU*ég%ÿ<ÿQ?0Â7Ûª–w}(·b,ö¬g‘§{¶§  ¯gú$\–Ç+Ä°¾ø|å£õy½öÙ8V=©gÐØ)öKx¶ØHBç½P×ÎÆ¿á½£ ÒýQÁþ"Ó¡ª³òO# ¾O#-UvÒ],¨v³œAÏéË-Éî§™³4)»¹áüx¡ÉEŸ£Ç÷Iæ¾L£Ÿ˜m{úªÛno¶?êTYé‡ÍìGÔ:Òy¹Å”«P]‘Ö}ÕtðÈpú8ÙùÆºFÐ ãˆÍ8v¤ÐFúk¡ç@•¼X”ÃüTèdf3g*YÆn´žUÀåížµ²,G/O›{% a°0½.ðMÍôSûÛÀ<Úñ…¥ÁYCÙMØàqy­”î ÀìlÛaS6^ÖI`?šàìLbáÒAš#¿àyE pž×"Há™ÚLÝó@ƒ¾×£"d(%$FTŸdVâ!ƒÊ< øGª›‚Ð~ß2vcÒÿ|kù™»‰†Á4SÜ}R¶(CAbvZ7AÕ¯O‹|Û7-ÊêïÊë±¼pWÈ(§ ÷HR2—¢I9t‘¥Íà;ÿt9q”úÊ¨TOyõá¡£‘îÉÈF– 5/4L“âK³„Þ_¶‡¦ÂTúP€`Î•W“SÆÜ=}2†‰þ¿„át\ô~w~Ž”£$E8²¤@rW³š³¸ƒÐÙäù¿¥ÀÇÚï]Szí´Å 6l˜§u›´a¡ ·§-Ø‚“½ëÇ— ¢);H ˆôAžBB#ÿq/3*¯gp©òHëZÎ«â‰‡ÚT!¤9"iP  ©€rº+)LZOÏo˜n»Âãâ›‰Ko³5’âZøºzrNÇœ i×ƒzEš9²7!jc’:î½¶7ã¹õ…ÙXàšÿŸ€S(x¬²ÏÞšÖaÅ×Â7}œÓ¯ô”±·68Ž$m¨\»­dÐa®Ô&}˜-+>Ô(FDdd-€W(r4†õ…õòãÊû¹QÜ»nÀ£&eFèö©Õ¢v/f§•QF|œR7Ðž•ã žÜHP p“ú¡ë6kûÂ=u”[wx7¹E·ãN&èß¹žaDGq3vÞ0(â:Ï‡1ŠÄK…´ìh[B˜De¤HÅ¬o% êÊÜ¸lÈgL‰iŽ þ>ßIz15¿ô½¬ÿÛÖ¨M$ÓÅŠ^¿ŠÁ(9szB@ncFç¼RZQI§Ð±R‚ëãn‡6&NìOêØMYžv=»Ë7[ª×©ÍÉš#f»`cAšd4L_;TÑj\&Bˆ3Ä³fBã’° -ËË]A‡` ÛT²ÃÒÇ¥°&ifÊ’rb8 ¥«ÁFÃÃ$ŠÎj«žsâ³”„Ö´âVßt@.

This is what is shown in network tab.

```
Request URL:http://opensourceeducation.in/downloader.php id=10b75aa66bcae680589f4fa43386454a
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=k05e15l3c5pp8gkdltrfngg0c0
Host:opensourceeducation.in
Referer:http://opensourceeducation.in/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
id:10b75aa66bcae680589f4fa43386454a
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sun, 05 Jan 2014 17:54:59 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

And yes i have shifted most of my codes into mysqli. These are few pages that are left.

Comment: That looks like a fine file. Are you sure you are sending the right `content-type` header?

Comment: You're making some serious SQL related mistakes. a) You're still using mysql_* functions.  Those are deprecated and will be removed from PHP at some point in the future.  They're also no longer supported or maintained and aren't built with modern versions of MySQL in mind.  b) You're wide open to an SQL injection attack. Don't include variables from outside your program directly in SQL strings.  Switch to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements instead of building SQL strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so resolved it. I just cleaned the white spaces outside my php code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a perfectly normal video file to me. It would see that your server isn't sending the `Content-Disposition` header correctly. I think it may be a requirement that the `filename` part be in quotes:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$result->ori_fname.'"');
```

If that doesn't fix it, use your browser's Developer Tools to see what headers are being received (Network tab) and let me know so I can try to help further :)